# Send mail from Java application

Tags: java, linux

I have Java application which is running on Linux Ubuntu.

My goal is to send email from this application using my own domain, with Java part everything is ok.

But do I need to install some mail server? If so, maybe you could suggest less complex one?

Maybe I can somehow use gmail or something else, but make emails show my domain?

Comment: If "with Java part everything is ok", what is not working? How did you test the Java part?

Comment: I mean understanding of Java part for me is ok, question is about mail server.

Comment: What question? Do you have a SMTP server?

Comment: No, that is what I need.

Comment: Then your question is off-topic here.

Comment: This question reads like "If I want to build software to automatically open a door, do I need a door?" Well no of course not, but if you don't have one your software is useless :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) , download these jars([here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.1_Release) for example) and read some [API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) , it is easy to send a email.

about how to make email show you domain , it is just a parameter

---

I think you are just writing a java project , which just need send someone a email , and you don't need to receive any email or something else .

JavaMail is enough.

---

Of course , this is the weakest and the easiest solution.

There are several better solution :

1. setup a email server in you os . just apt xxx ,etc. is ok.
2. send via gmail . you just need a ordinary google account , some user may have tip with words like "send by yourdomain.com via  xxx@gmail.com"
3. some website(hotmail and gmail are both ok , if you know Chinese , [this](http://edu.exmail.qq.com/) is also fine ) support some special email account , and you just need add some information in you dns.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but isnt that kind of email being blocked as spam messages?

Comment: @sandris you may use smtp.jar, send via gmail.